# highcharter - where are the already downloaded maps for hcmap() stored on a (shiny) server?

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, r-highcharter

**My setup:** I am using two `selectizeInputs` togehter with `hcmap()` in order to display a world map (this one [custom/world-palestine-highres](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/mapdata/custom/world-palestine-highres)) where users can change the institute and the variable they want to look at. Hence, the map gets rendered often!
In this process, I downloaded the map multiple times via testing/rendering the app till I found the `options(highcharter.download_map_data = FALSE)` while browsing through your repository - the [vignette](https://rdrr.io/cran/highcharter/man/hcmap.html)  on how to use `download_map_data` is not that clear tbh. However, now the map gets rendered without downloading itself again --> perfect!

**Now to my question:** Where does the map get stored on the server when downloaded the first time? Because with my current setup, no user will download the map again (which is what I want), but what if we have to restart the server or move files? I just want to make sure that I dont have to service the app all the time in regards to map downloads.

**EDIT#1:** Code samples for JBKunst, as the new code doesn't show any data

My hcmap code I used before:

```
hcmap("custom/world-palestine-highres", data = datapool_credit, joinBy = c("hc-a2", "Country"), value = capital_variable,
      name = capital_variable,
      dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = '{point.name}'),
      borderColor = "#FAFAFA", borderWidth = 0.1,
      tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 0, valuePrefix = "€", valueSuffix = "")) %>%
  hc_mapNavigation(enabled = TRUE)
```

The new code as suggested by JBKunst:

```
highchart(type = "map") %>%
  hc_add_series(
    mapData = JS("Highcharts.maps['custom/world-palestine-highres']"),
    data = datapool_credit, joinBy = c("hc-key"), joinBy = c("hc-a2", "Country"), value = capital_variable,
    name = capital_variable,
    dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = '{point.name}'),
    borderColor = "#FAFAFA", borderWidth = 0.1,
    tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 0, valuePrefix = "€", valueSuffix = "")) %>%
  hc_mapNavigation(enabled = TRUE)
```

**EDIT#2:** structure of used data for the map (changed the numbers for data privacy reasons, but not the format)

```
> dput(head(datapool_credit))
structure(list(Country = c("AE", "AF", "AL", "AM", "AO", "AQ"
), PD = c(0.506010018321176, 64.350505, 8.94600128868667, 14.29401046096271, 
25.0439479, 3.5626)), .Names = c("Country", "PD"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x244ccb8>)
```

Best regards,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like https://github.com/jbkunst/shiny-apps/tree/master/highcharter-maps-performance

You don't need to store the map. Instead the user will read from `https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world-palestine-highres.js` one time per session just like the highcharts example:

In your `ui.R` you need to add the map

```
# ui.R
...
tags$script(src = "https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world-palestine-highres.js")
...
```

Then in the `server.R` don't use the `hcmap`, instead use `highchart()`:

```
# server.R
...
highchart(type = "map") %>% 
  hc_add_series(
    mapData = JS("Highcharts.maps["custom/world-palestine-highres"]"),
    data = data, joinBy = c("hc-key")
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! As soon as I get back to the app, I will implement your proposed steps and report back to you

Comment: Hi, I tried to implement your code, but now the map doesn't show any data - just a plain grey map.
Please see my edit#1 in my post for the two code samples, as the comment section is too small to post them here.

Comment: Try to put a `dput` of `head(datapool_credit)` in the question to see the data

Comment: Sorry for the really late reply - I added the dput in my question in EDIT#2.

Comment: Just want to add to @jbkunst's answer. As of Aug. 21, you can just use `download_map_data = FALSE` and keep using `hcmap`, in conjunction with the `tags$script` in `ui.R`. Nothing else needs to change.